# IOS/Swift : HERE MAPS not clearing map markers on map (Explore edition)

Tags: here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk, here-ios

I have used both the lite sdk and the explore sdk available for the swift ios, for integration with here maps.
I haven't passed by any of the ways to clear map markers already set on a screen on the mapview.
Kindly let me if any workaround is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `MapMarker` items with the HERE SDK for iOS (Explore Edition) by calling:

```
mapView.mapScene.removeMapMarker(mapMarker)
```

Make sure that the `mapMarker` is the same instance you have added before, otherwise, the code will do nothing.

In case of doubt, try the [MapItems](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/ios/MapItems) example app on GitHub. In this [line](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/44cd9edf608d365016227e3d5931ad9671fbe2de/examples/latest/explore/ios/MapItems/MapItems/MapItemsExample.swift#L252) it shows how to remove all added markers.

Comment: My use case was to clear all the map markers that had been added to the map scene. However, your mapView.mapScene.removeMapMarker(mapMarker) only removes  a given particular marker.

The work around i used was to store the instance of each marker in a an array or some datastore object and then call the removeMapMarker on each instance.

It did my work.